# Pass "state" from Hydra /oauth2/auth to my login page

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm working on an "extension system" where 3rd party systems can extend the functionality of my app. Logged-in users open my native app, browse for "extensions" they like, and then click "Connect".

As per standard Hydra flow, the first step is to send user to this URL:

```
https://HYDRA.MYAPP.COM/oauth2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&state=SOME_STATE&prompt=consent&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&response_type=code&scope=MY_SCOPE
```

Which, in turn, will send user to the login page:

```
https://MYAPP.COM/login?login_challenge=SOME_CHALLENGE
```

**My question:** How do I retrieve `SOME_STATE` in my login page logic?

This flow is initiated from a native mobile app (which will open a webview), so I don't want the user to login again. Instead, the app will pass the encrypted user id inside `SOME_STATE`.

### Full picture:

1. User opens my native app (Android/iOS/Desktop).
2. User opens "Integrations" screen and clicks "Connect with X".
3. App relays the request to backend.
4. Backend returns URL `https://HYDRA.MYAPP.COM/oauth2/auth...`. The URL's `state` param contains encrypted user id for "auto login" purpose.
5. Embedded webview opens the URL, then redirects to Consent Screen.
6. User clicks Approve, webview is dismissed.
7. Link between my app and X is now established.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work in OAuth systems, since the core protocol messages will result in redirects that drop custom parameters.

If you have already signed into your native app, then the standard SSO session cookie should give you the behaviour you need when 'connecting with X'.

Even if the user needs to sign in again (which might be true in iOS), password auto fill should make it a single click.

A few questions so that I understand your scenario, after which I'll update my answer to be more specific:

- What type of native app do you have (eg desktop / iOS / Android)?
- Do your native app logins use web views? (these are private browsers that usually cannot share SSO cookies or passwords).

Comment: I've updated my question with the information you need, hopefully it'll give you more clarity.

Comment: Why should you have to do an OAuth redirect for the 'third party systems'? Most commonly a third party system would have its own data / APIs and its own Authorization Server ...